# How to install phpwkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, composer-php, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to install phpwkhtmltopdf on shared server (webhotel). The server has already composer installed, and I have SSH to server. But I am not too familiar with composer so I might be doing someting very basic wrong here..

So, I have downloaded the zip file from:
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
 and extracted the files on it to server to directory named as phpwkhtmltopdf.
Then, opening SSH cd-ing to that dir and running composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf but I only get question marks to beginning of line. 
For the question marks I read that it could be a problem of detect unicode, so I placed to htaccess: php_flag detect_unicode Off and it seems that it is Off now locally.

But there is still the question marks and php wkhtmltopdf does not get installed. How to get it installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are fetching the package `mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf` two times:

- firstly, you fetched the zip and extracted it (manual installation).
- then, you ran Composer to require it (installation via Composer).

Please decide how you want to install the package!

---

When you want to install the package with Composer, you just need to run `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf` in a clean project folder.

Composer will then fetch the package and place it into the `/vendor` folder.

That's it.

---

Now, in order to use it you need two things:

1. you need to include Composers Autoloader during the bootstrap of your project. This enables that the Autoloader will load the library, when you access one the package/library classes.

   ```
   // Register Composer Autoloader

   define('VENDOR_DIR', __DIR__ . '\vendor' . DS);

   if (!is_file(VENDOR_DIR . 'autoload.php')) {
       throw new \RuntimeException(
           '[Error] Bootstrap: Could not find "vendor/autoload.php".' . PHP_EOL .
           'Did you forget to run "composer install --dev"?' . PHP_EOL
       );
   }

   require VENDOR_DIR . 'autoload.php';
   ```
2. Well, finally, you need to code something using the library:

   ```
   use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

   $pdf = new Pdf('/path/to/page.html');

   if (!$pdf->saveAs('/path/to/page.pdf')) {
       echo $pdf->getError();
   }
   ```

Uhm, and you need the wkhtmltopdf binary... but i guess thats not the problem.

---

These are my steps:

1. i downloaded wkhtmltopdf http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3.2/wkhtmltox-0.12.3.2_msvc2013-win64.exe
2. and installed it into `c:\program files\wkhtmltopdf`
3. now the executable resides in `c:\program files\wkhtmltopdf\bin`
4. i created the folder `pdf-test`
5. i ran the command `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf` on the CLI
6. i created a file `makepdf.php` with the following content:

   ```
   /**
    * Register Composer Autloader
    */
   define('VENDOR_DIR', __DIR__ . '\vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

   if (!is_file(VENDOR_DIR . 'autoload.php')) {
       throw new \RuntimeException(
           '[Error] Bootstrap: Could not find "vendor/autoload.php".' . PHP_EOL .
           'Did you forget to run "composer install --dev"?' . PHP_EOL
       );
   }

   require VENDOR_DIR . 'autoload.php';

   /**
    * Use library
    */

   use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;


   $pdf = new Pdf(array(
       'binary' => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe',
       'ignoreWarnings' => true,
       'commandOptions' => array(
           'procEnv' => array(
               // Check the output of 'locale' on your system to find supported languages
               'LANG' => 'en_US.utf-8',
           ),
           'escapeArgs' => false,
           'procOptions' => array(
               // This will bypass the cmd.exe which seems to be recommended on Windows
               'bypass_shell' => true,
               // Also worth a try if you get unexplainable errors
               'suppress_errors' => true,
           ),
       ),
   ));

   $pdf->addPage('<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>

       <div id="print-area">
           <div id="header">
               This is an example header.
           </div>
           <div id="content">
               <h1>Demo</h1>
               <p>This is example content</p>
           </div>
           <div id="footer">
               This is an example footer.
           </div>
       </div>

   </body>
   </html>');

   if (!$pdf->saveAs('page.pdf')) {
       echo $pdf->getError();
   }
   ```
7. then i ran `php makepdf.php`
8. finally, the file `page.pdf` was generated

And that's it... :)

Comment: Thanks Jens already, but few problems still:
I would prefer the installation via Composer as it is suggested method, and was then running that composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf in an emtpy folder. But getting again only question marks to beginning of next line. Then I tried also the manual version, including the 3 files at Src dir to my test file (having similar content to your step 2.), but just got the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mikehaertl\shellcommand\Command' not found in /home/testdomain/public_html/Command.php on line 17. Thus, I think it is missing some files

Comment: Ok, i tried to reproduce it, but failed. I've updated my answer and included all the steps i executed to get `page.pdf` generated. Please let me know if this also works for you.

Comment: Thanks again, but I still didn't get it to work: The reason seems to be that I cannot get composer to gather needed resources - all I get is the question marks when running that command.
Also, I am running it at Linux environment as I am trying to build same thing to share webserver. For the sake of testing, I also tried jut to manually extract the linux versions of the exe's to server and running same code (with modifications to path to exe accordingly), but it seems to need more than I have from manual installation.

Comment: It seems we have to sort out the Composer issue first. Please run `composer selfupdate` followed by `composer diagnose`on the CLI. The `diagnose` command will run some checks on your enviroment to make sure Composer works. Maybe it shows the reason for the Composer issue (question marks).

Comment: It seems odd. When I run either of the commands you mentioned, both return same four question marks at the next line. Maybe the composer has some installation problem. I will consult the hosting provider of the shared server as they have installed it. There is multiple threads about same issue with composer, but all seem to relate to detect_unicode which should be off to make it work. Since it already is Off (locally, not as Master value), I am not sure what is the cause of this. You have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a unicode problem while running Composer. Referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15219058/1163786 # I hope you have access to a console. You could try to run PHP with deactivated unicode and then Composer, e.g. `php -d detect_unicode=Off composer.phar install`. # One small tip and workaround: It seems you are trying to run Composer on a production machine. You could try to run Composer on the development machine and package your application (including dependencies) for deployment. You would then only unzip on the production machine and have no need to run Composer there.

Comment: Thank you Jens for all the help! I got if finally working (well, not the define-part yet for some reason but I replaced it with require 'vendor/autoload.php'; for now).
The reason it was not working was that server had some settings incorrectly for composer (the detect_unicode was not affecting). I actually had to change server too, but anyway, now it is working. :)